# How do I change the color of eventbrite embed button and hover color?

Tags: css, wordpress

Not sure how to make the button color change and as well as the hover color change. Please let me know how to code this into the text editor/ CSS for WordPress. Below is the embed code that is given.

```
<noscript><a href="https://www.eventbrite.com/e/test-1-tickets-53170478332" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"></noscript>
<button id="eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-53170478332" type="button">BUY NOW</button>
<noscript><strong></a>Buy Tickets on Eventbrite</strong></noscript>
```

Comment: <noscript><a href="https://www.eventbrite.com/e/test-1-tickets-53170478332" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"></noscript>
<button id="eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-53170478332" type="button">BUY NOW</button>
<noscript><strong></a>Buy Tickets on Eventbrite</strong></noscript>

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<style>`-tag and add CSS-styles for your button's ID. You could also create a class if you want to use more than one button.

In this example your ID is: **eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-53170478332**

Then write your styles for that ID or the class you created.

```html
<noscript><a href="https://www.eventbrite.com/e/test-1-tickets-53170478332" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"></noscript>
<button id="eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-53170478332" type="button" >BUY NOW</button>
<noscript><strong></a>Buy Tickets on Eventbrite</strong></noscript>
<style>
#eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-53170478332 {
border: none; 
background: darkorange; 
color: #FFF;
border-radius: 4px;
transition: all 300ms linear;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0.5em;
}
#eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-53170478332:hover {
background: red; 
}
</style>
```